# How to prevent execCommand('SaveAs', from opening new tab or window

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9, domdocument, execcommand

I have to generate a download pop up in IE.
Iam using the below code.
when i click on buttton it opens a new tab and the Save as Dialogue box

```
 function SaveContents(element) {

            if (document.execCommand) {
                var oWin = window.open("about:blank","_blank");![enter image description here][1]
                oWin.document.write(element);
                oWin.document.close();
                var success = oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', false, "FilteredReport.xls")
                oWin.close();

            }

}
```

How can i make the Save as Dialogue box appear with out opening new window or tab..

Also can i write data of a string to excel with out using

```
oWin.document.write(element);
```

beacuse its getting written to the new tab or window that opens

Below image explains..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".xls");` use below snippet

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
     blobObject = new Blob([CSV]);
     window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, 'Export.xls');
 }
IEwindow.close();
```

Comment: window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob is undefined! did I miss something?  IEwindows is also not recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

include an iframe with ID    IframeForExcelExportonIE

```
<iframe id="IframeForExcelExportonIE" style="display: none"></iframe>

IframeForExcelExportonIE.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
IframeForExcelExportonIE.document.write(cln.innerHTML);
IframeForExcelExportonIE.document.close();
IframeForExcelExportonIE.focus();
sa = IframeForExcelExportonIE.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, " test.xls");
```

Comment: @AzharShahazad its not working on me look http://plnkr.co/edit/8oDrrIyn0XSduagYtadK?p=preview